# How to create a writeStream of a remote file using request?

Tags: node.js, npm-request

I'm trying to achieve it using following code as mentioned in npm-request but I get

```
TypeError: Object #<WriteStream> has no method 'pause'

request('https://www.google.com.np/images/srpr/logo11w.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.pdf'));
```

Cant seem to figure out, could be because of async .. is there a sync way ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What version of node are you using? I have used this code to test your problem and it works perfectly for me

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

request('https://www.google.com.np/images/srpr/logo11w.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.pdf'));
```